# Requests ImportError: No module named 'requests' on windows

Tags: python-3.x

I've successfully install requests on windows using these commands:
Path> setup.py install.
But when i run this code ,an error is same.
Please tell me the solution.

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://gabe-wise.com")

r.content

Error is: **ImportError: No module named 'requests'**

Comment: Did you do `pip install requests`?

Answer (score 1):

you should install requests

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

See the installation doc
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/